# Excel Calender Template (Weekday)

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I use Excel 2016. In the template, I found **Academic calender (any year)**. The template is very awesome (for me).
Then, I try to learn the formula. I found the formula in cell C4 like this:

```
=Days+1+DATE(Calendar1Year,Calendar1MonthOption,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(Calendar1Year,Calendar1MonthOption,1),WeekdayOption)
```

I learn the **WeekdayOption** in Weekday function base on combobox in cell B3 (image below)
[Question1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09FgG.png)

My question is how WeekdayOption accept word like SUNDAY or MONDAY or TUESDAY or other ? I know it can accept value 11, 12, 13, etc. Can anyone explain how it works or trick to do it ?

The template link is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LMnzu1UpC-eGxtb2FhMkRROGc/view?usp=sharing) or you can download from excel template.
Thanks you.

Comment: If you look at WeekdayOption in Name Manager, what is the formula or address it refers to?

Comment: btw Teman saya dari Medan; Halo ke Medan.

Comment: Hello @D_Bester . I have found the answer.Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get enlightenment from your comment [D_Bester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2559297/d-bester).
I found the trick in Name Manager (Formulas Tab).

I will explain the trick :

The build-in function : **WEEKDAY(serial_number,[return_type])**. [Return type] use WeekdayOption in Name Manager.

In Name Manager : `WeekdayOption` Refers to :`=MATCH(WeekStart,Weekdays,0)+10`

Then : `WeekStart` Refers to : `=Sheet1!$B$3`

Then : `Weekdays` Refers to : `={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"}`

So, if in cell B3 the text is **Monday**, the **WeekdayOption will Return 11** (Monday will return 1 in array; 1 + 10 = 11)

If in cell B3 the text is **Tuesday**, the **WeekdayOption will Return 12** (Tuesday will return 2 in array; 2 + 10 = 12)

Comment: That's great! See you on vacation at Danau Toba. Indonesia is amazing!